# Ember getting error 404 (Not OK) with no code changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ember.js

This morning I got to work and tried to run my app (like every other day) and got GET http://localhost:60589/Index.html?prvdRetarg 404 (Not OK) on console. I haven't done any changes to my code which didn't have any errors yesterday. Any ideas on what may have caused this?

Comment: Do you test with cache enabled? Cause it could have expired.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the error was coming from privdog that must've been installed when I installed something else, so I just uninstalled it to make the error disappear and it worked